# How to know a link is opened by clicking a button from outside in angular

Tags: angular

I have UI link,if some one click that link through a button from another page,Angular UI need to know link is clicked through the button

Comment: you could set a query param on that button, and on the navigated route, check for query params in the activatedRoute Snapshot to know if its comes from that button, one possible way

Comment: I dont need to change the url.If i am adding the query params,the url will change right..Is there an soultion other than this

Comment: you can create a variable in the service, and then set it when button is clicked. In the navigated route, get that value from service to figure out if button is clicked. Helps?

Comment: How to know the button is  clicked and opened the url?

Comment: check my answer, let me know if this works?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Create a service ButtonState

```
export service ButtonState() {
public buttonClicked = false;

getButtonClicked() {
  return buttonClicked;
}

setButtonClicked() {

   this.buttonClicked = true;
}

resetButtonState() {
   this.buttonClicked = false;
}

}
```

In your html where you click the button

```
<button (click)="clickBtn()">Click</button>
```

In the component where button is present

```
clickBtn() { 
this.buttonStateService.setButtonClicked();

// Code for route navigate

}
```

In your Navigated Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
const isButtonClicked = this.buttonStateService.getButtonClicked;

}
```